# On an airliner, how do the seats at the front of a row handle the food tray and the entertainment system?

Tags: aircraft

For clarity, I will be flying on a BA Boeing 777-200 or 777-300. Our seats will be at the front of premium economy.

On most seats there is another seat in front where the folding tray table and the entertainment system are all hooked into. Obviously when you get to the front of any class in the plane, there will be an extended gap where there are no seats in front are close enough to serve as a usable anchor for the tray and entertainment system?

The seats I am talking about for example would be any in row 26 or rows 21

[image: Layout for a BA 777-200]

Comment: They just fold out.

Answer (score 4):

In the first rows of economy, those tables fold out of the armrest. It is normally slightly wider than the armrests behind, and closed, to contain the folded table.
This works fine, unless your legs are much thicker than average, then it would not fit over them.

Answer (score 3):

It will be something like the image pictured below, the video screen will come out on an arm from the front of the seat.   The tray table will come out from the middle arm rest folded in two.

[[image: Premium Economy Aircraft seat]]

Comment: On all the planes I have been on, that is true for the table, but the video screen is mounted on the bulkhead in front.

Comment: I've seen that as well, I know the economy BA 777 ones are like the picture.
I've just checked a photo I took from when I flew BA PE a few weeks ago and there were no screens on the bulkhead

Comment: @WGroleau, both types are common.  More and more (2017) planes *just don't have* video screens.  They have the "free movies via wifi" system, and you just watch crappy movies on your own device.

Comment: After you pay for WiFi to download their app.